# JOIN multiple tables, concatenate name strings, and hierarchically group data

Tags: php, mysql, join, hierarchical-data

I have been trying to get details from Contacts table, from  Another table with Id's for these contacts, I think it has to do with logic, I am not not a pro yet.

These are my **Tables**:

**g3cc_cntcts_and_employers:**

```
id | employer_id | employee_id | verified | active  
1  |     1       |     2           1          1
2  |     1       |     3           1          0
3  |     1       |     4           0          1
4  |     1       |     5           0          0
5  |     1       |     5           0          0
6  |     6       |     7           1          1
7  |     6       |     4           0          0
```

**g3cc_contactus:**

```
id   |  nombre  |   apellidos
1    |  BOSS    |     CEO
2    |  Perry   |    Smith
3    |  John    |     Doe
4    |  Jane    |    Malme
5    |  Mary    |    Johnson
6    |  Another |    Employer
7    |  Ann     |    Clark
```

**Desired Report:**

```
Employer And Employees
    BOSS CEO
        Perry Smith  | 1  |  1
        John Doe     | 1  |  0
        Jane Malme   | 0  |  1
        Mary Johnson | 0  |  0

Another Employer
    Jane Malme   | 0  |  0
    Ann Clark    | 1  |  1
```

I already tried from examples from this and other places, I have two queries but I still can't get it to work.

**`My Qry 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, nombre, apellidos
    FROM g3cc_contactus
    WHERE id=285
    GROUP BY 1  
) id JOIN (
    SELECT employee_id, active, verified
    FROM g3cc_cntcts_and_employers
    GROUP BY 1  
) employee_id;
```

**My Qry 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id, username 
    FROM g3cc_contactus) a
JOIN
(SELECT employer_id, employee_id
    FROM g3cc_cntcts_and_employers) b
ON a.id = b.employer_id AND a.id = b.employee_id;
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question. There should be help and a preview. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get raw data, you could try with:

```
SELECT
    e.nombre || ' ' || e.apellidos AS Employer,
    c.nombre || ' ' || c.apellidos AS Employee,
    ec.verified,
    ec.active
FROM
    g3cc_cntcts_and_employers ec
JOIN
    g3cc_contactus e ON ec.employer_id = e.id
JOIN
    g3cc_contactus c ON ec.employee_id = c.id
ORDER BY
    e.nombre, e.apellidos, c.nombre, c.apellidos;
```

If you want to get exact result you have to write some PHP.

Comment: in mysql || is shorthand for logical OR (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html)- use concat instead.